# How to store data from a stopwatch javascript to MySQL

Tags: java, php, database, timer, stopwatch

I have a java stopwatch script and I really don't remember where I get it.

This script works fine, but what I need is when the stop button is pressed or the start button  is pressed to store the data in the MySQL.

The Javascript is here: http://landingpage.al/script.js

The purpose of this is that I will have some user that will do different things on a work space and on each state of the work their work time will be calculated and stored.

So if anyone have a better idea will be helpful.

The actual php timer is here: http://landingpage.al/articolo100.php

Comment: with stored in MySQL what do you mean? UPDATE an existing row or insert new rows? Add what you have tried so far here...

Comment: please add actual PHP code here as we can't see it thru link (its not available on client-end). Share more about your database tables structure.

Comment: Put the timer and the buttons in a html form and link the start/stop buttons to a php script which updates the db

Comment: hello user956959 this is what I wanted to do but the display of the dimer is <input type='text' id='disp' name='koha' /> and the start/stop buttons are <button type='button' name='fillo' onclick='ss()' >Start</button> this calls the functions from javascript so I need that the time diplayed <input type='text' id='disp' name='koha' /> get inserted into DB. could this be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form:

```
<div id="main">
<form name="input" id="myform" action="here.php" method="post">
<button type="button" id="1" name="fillo" onclick="ss();start()">Start</button>
<button type="button" id="2" name="mbaro" onclick="ss();start()" onfocus="this.blur()">Stop</button>
<input type="text" id="disp" name="koha"> <br>
</form>
```

Script:

```
<script>
function start(){
document.getElementById("myform").submit();
}
</script>
```

PHP for here.php:

```
<?php
echo $_POST['koha']; //Use the update command instead of echo
?>
```

Comment: The only problem is that the data get inserted after I press start again not when I press stop... and how the here.php can be load in hidden without going to the page. can this be done

Comment: If you include the js function in the ss() function which is in the script.js file it will work on the stop button as well. You should use AJAX if you don't want to get redirected